# How to include .war file as a java web project dependency in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, war

I have a WAR file which contains some web application.
I have created a new java web application and i want to use some classes of the WAR which i already have.
How to add the WAR file as a dependency in my new Java Web Application in using eclipse.
I am running this application in Tomcat 7.0 server.

Thanks & Regards,
Rahul

Comment: I haven't use any build tool like Ant or maven yet!! But planning now maven may help me i think.

Comment: A better idea would be to put the classes in their own jar file and then deploy that jar file in both web applications. Maven can indeed help to manage that better.

Answer (score 3):

A WAR file is not intended as a dependency, it has a structure specifically designed for deployment to application servers (that understand that structure).

I would move the classes you want to depend on into a separate jar and then have both the war project and your new project depend on it.

You could also create a client jar from the war project which your new application could depend on. However, if you go down the maven route, the Sonatype tutorial will say that each maven project should only produce one artifact.